# PYTHON problem with negative decimals

Tags: python, list, floating-point, max, min

I have a list of negative floats. I want to make a histogram with them. As far as I know, Python can't do operations with negative numbers. Is this correct? The list is like [-0.2923998, -1.2394875, -0.23086493, etc.]. I'm trying to find the maximum and minimum number so I can find out what the range is. My code is giving an error:

```
setrange = float(maxv) - float(minv)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

And this is the code:

```
f = open('clusters_scores.out','r')
#first, extract all of the sim values
val = []
for line in f:
    lineval = line.split()
    print lineval
    val.append(lineval)
print val
#val = map(float,val)
maxv = max(val)
minv = min(val)
setrange = float(maxv) - float(minv)
```

All the values that are being put into the 'val' list are negative decimals. What is the error referring to, and how do I fix it?

The input file looks like:

```
-0.0783532095182 -0.99415440702 -0.692972552716 -0.639273674023 -0.733029194040.765257900121 -0.755438339963
-0.144140594077 -1.06533353638 -0.366278118372 -0.746931508538 -1.02549039392 -0.296715961215
-0.0915937502791 -1.68680560936 -0.955147543358
-0.0488457137771 -0.0943080192383 -0.747534412969 -1.00491121699
-1.43973471463
-0.0642611118901 -0.0910684525497
-1.19327387414 -0.0794696449245
-1.00791366035 -0.0509749096549
-1.08046507281 -0.957339914505 -0.861495748259
```

Comment: there is no problem with negative numbers in Python.

Comment: I've edited my answer substantially to account for the new information in your sample input file.

Comment: "Python can't do operations with negative numbers" !! Astounding what some people will conclude is the source of their problem...

Comment: One of these days, those Python devs will get that pesky negative number problem fixed!!! (although this only affects less than half of all numbers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The results of `split()` are a list of split values, which is probably why you are getting that error.

For example, if you do `'-0.2'.split()`, you get back a list with a single value `['-0.2']`.

EDIT: Aha! With your input file provided, it looks like this is the problem: `-0.733029194040.765257900121`. I think you mean to make that two separate floats?

Assuming a corrected file like this:

```
-0.0783532095182 -0.99415440702 -0.692972552716 -0.639273674023 -0.733029194040 -0.765257900121 -0.755438339963
-0.144140594077 -1.06533353638 -0.366278118372 -0.746931508538 -1.02549039392 -0.296715961215
-0.0915937502791 -1.68680560936 -0.955147543358
-0.0488457137771 -0.0943080192383 -0.747534412969 -1.00491121699
-1.43973471463
-0.0642611118901 -0.0910684525497
-1.19327387414 -0.0794696449245
-1.00791366035 -0.0509749096549
-1.08046507281 -0.957339914505 -0.861495748259
```

The following code will no longer throw that exception:

```
f = open('clusters_scores.out','r')
#first, extract all of the sim values
val = []
for line in f:
    linevals = line.split()
    print linevals
    val += linevals
print val
val = map(float, val)
maxv = max(val)
minv = min(val)
setrange = float(maxv) - float(minv)
```

I have changed it to take the list result from split() and concatenate it to the list, rather than append it, which will work provided there are valid inputs in your file.

Comment: `split` gives you array of strings, so you have to convert them to floats

Comment: But when I try to do that, there's an error that says "Could not convert string() to float" or something similar.....

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide a version of your code that does not throw the error.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out - the oldest rule in computing.

Answer (score 1):

> All the values that are being put into the 'val' list are negative decimals.

No, they aren't; they're *lists of* strings that represent negative decimals, since the `.split()` call produces a list. `maxv` and `minv` are lists of strings, which can't be fed to `float()`.

> What is the error referring to, and how do I fix it?

It's referring to the fact that the contents of `val` aren't what you think they are. The first step in debugging is to verify your assumptions. If you try this code out at the REPL, then you could inspect the contents of `maxv` and `minv` and notice that you have lists of strings rather than the expected strings.

I assume you want to put all the lists of strings (from each line of the file) together into a single list of strings. Use `val.extend(lineval)` rather than `val.append(lineval)`.

That said, you'll still want to `map` the strings into floats before calling `max` or `min` because otherwise you will be comparing the strings as strings rather than floats. (It might well work, but explicit is better than implicit.)

Simpler yet, just read the entire file at once and split it; `.split()` without arguments splits on whitespace, and a newline is whitespace. You can also do the `map`ping at the same point as the reading, with careful application of a list comprehension. I would write:

```
with open('clusters_scores.out') as f:
  val = [float(x) for x in f.read().split()]
result = max(val) - min(val)
```